# NgChartjs Bar chart bars color not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, bar-chart

Hey guys I am having a problem with ng-chartjs. I am trying to give specific color to each bar but they all take the same color and the color is not at all the color that i am trying to give when i try to give only one color.

I am using [ng-chartjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-chartjs).

I am doing the same logic in a doughnut chart but is working.

[Actual Bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyMjj.png)

How I want the colors

[Desired Bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xzs9.png)

**Bar char html code**

```
    <div>
      <div>
        <canvas
          ngChartjs
          [datasets]="lineChartData"
          [labels]="lineChartLabels"
          [options]="lineChartOptions"
          [legend]="true"
          [chartType]="chartType"
        ></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Ts Bar chart code**

```
  chartType = 'bar';
 
  lineChartData: Array<any> = [
    {
      label: 'Student',
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgb(255, 35, 35)',
        'rgb(255,114,114)',
        'rgb(249,181,107)',
        'rgb(238,215,107)',
        'rgb(255,217,65)',
        'rgb(0,187,149)',
        'rgb(0,228,189)',
        'rgb(107,238,212)',
      ],
    
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
    
      pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
     
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: [12, 12, 10, 22, 15, 20, 25, 30],
      barPercentage: 0.11,
    },
  ];
 
  lineChartLabels: Array<any> = [
    '0 pike',
    '15 pike',
    '30 pike',
    '45 pike',
    '60 pike',
    '75 pike',
    '90 pike',
    '100 pike',
  ];

  
  lineChartOptions: any = {
    responsive: true,
    
    chartArea: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      
      position: 'top',
    },
    legend: {
      
      display: false,
    },
    layout: {
      padding: 50,
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          gridLines: {
            borderDash: [10],
            color: 'rgb(23,6,100)',
            drawBorder: false,
          },
          ticks: {
           
            beginAtZero: true,
            stepSize: 10,
          },
        },
      ],
      xAxes: [
        {
          gridLines: {
           
            display: false,
            drawBorder: false,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the directive's `[color]` the set your colors like shown in the following.

Add this to your `bar-chart.ts`:

```
colors: Array<any> = [
    'rgb(255, 35, 35)',
    'rgb(255,114,114)',
    'rgb(249,181,107)',
    'rgb(238,215,107)',
    'rgb(255,217,65)',
    'rgb(0,187,149)',
    'rgb(0,228,189)',
    'rgb(107,238,212)'
]
```

and modify your `bar-chart.html` like this:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <canvas
      ngChartjs
      [datasets]="lineChartData"
      [labels]="lineChartLabels"
      [options]="lineChartOptions"
      [colors]="[{ backgroundColor: colors, hoverBackgroundColor: colors }]"
      [legend]="true"
      [chartType]="chartType"
    ></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can both set a `backgroundColor`'s and `hoverBackgroundColor`'s.

Here is a [running stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fdg8wv?file=src/app/app.component.html) resulting in this view:

[image: Resulting view]

Good luck!

Comment: Hey Tommy thanks a lot man i have been struggling with this the pas 2 days and i couldn't find any ng-chartjs documentation or anything.